# How do I find the manifold absolute pressure sensor on a 1998Honda Accord

Tags: honda, accord, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor

Where is the manifold absolute pressure sensor at on a 1998 Honda accord? I have tried looking on YouTube but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Is it not right at the end of the induction pipe, just before it connects to the intake manifold?

Answer (score 2):

In most vehicles you can find the Manifold Absolute Pressure sensor in the intake manifold.

It is the same case with your vehicle.

[image]

Follow the black tube from the front of the engine and you will see the sensor.